# Geohash KeyError when reading in CSV

Tags: python, csv, keyerror, geohashing

I'm trying to read in a CSV of geohashes, to be converted to lat/longs.  I'm using Python's Geohash module.  Here's my code:

```
import Geohash
import csv
with open('C:\Users\Data\myData.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        geoHash = row[0]
        print(str(geoHash)) #This prints sucessfully
        geoStr = str(geoHash)
        Geohash.decode(geoStr) #This fails
```

The code only fails on the very last line, `geoStr` outputs each geohash successfully.  The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File

```
"C:/Users/PycharmProjects/GeoHash/GeoHash_to_LatLong.py", line 11, in <module>
    Geohash.decode(geoStr)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\GeoHash\venv\lib\site-packages\Geohash\geohash.py", line 68, in decode
    lat, lon, lat_err, lon_err = decode_exactly(geohash)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\GeoHash\venv\lib\site-packages\Geohash\geohash.py", line 44, in decode_exactly
    cd = __decodemap[c]
KeyError: 'o'
```

I've checked the CSV and there doesn't appear to be any odd characters or anything that would cause this to fail.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the _exact_ output of `print(str(geoHash))`?

Comment: Is the last line of your CSV file empty?  If not, add the line to your question to allow us to recreate the problem.

Comment: "0123456789bcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz" these characters can be present in a geohash. 'o' is in an invalid character. When the decode encounters an invalid char it will throw an error.